# Rich Text Field in Community not displaying correct icons?

Tags: visualforce, community, richtextarea

We have been using rich text field from years, but recently we observed that there is some issue with it in community. 
I created a simple VF with just rich text field in it. This works properly inside salesforce.
[image]

But, same VF in community looks like this
[image]

Anyone aware about this issue?

Comment: Please check if this is the issue https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000264419&type=1&language=en_US

Comment: @SarojBera i tried doing same. As well as tried by new installed browser and on completely new PC, but same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering directly, but have enough reputation to put a comment.

This link [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001BrFQAU) mentions that when Locker Services are enabled in the org, Rich text-area fields work in classic but do not show properly in other views. This is applicable for Communities as well.

As a resolution (temporary one) you can disable Locker Services and check if they have any impact on the Rich Text area fields.

This will be resolved when Locker Services are auto-enabled in Summer 17 release.

Comment: My sandbox is Summer 17 enabled, as well as, i am not sure if this is applicable for Communities or not. Because this works in my production, issue is with all my sandbox's. And upto what i have seen is, in locker services, the Rich Text is disabled, whereas this is just icons displayed incorrectly

Comment: If so, I suspect it has something to do with cache. Have you tried deleting the cache and then doing a hard reload using Chrome Dev Console?

Comment: Yes, i tried doing so. Also, opened same in completely new PC where salesforce was opened for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

This was reported in multiple complaints in both 'answers' and the developers forums. The solution is to clear the browser. 
My assumption is that it relates to a recent bug/change in SalesForce implementation of the CKEditor.  No official statement or customer notification from SalesForce as of yet.

Comment: hey can you point me to the forum link if possible?

Comment: sure. here's a reference of one such thread: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?feedtype=RECENT&criteria=BESTANSWERS#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=Customer_Service_Support&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS&id=9063A000000Dma8QAC